# How should I name my server in nginx if I have a redirect server and the main server?

Tags: nginx, web-server, web

Suppose my main server is to serve `https://www.example.com` and the redirect server is to redirect `http://www.example.com` to `https://www.example.com`. How should I name these two servers? Is there a sort of best practice for this?

Is server name mostly a personal preference such that I can name anything?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/189912

Answer (score 1):

They should be both named `www.example.com`. This name often is actually quite important because if you host more than one virtual host on the same IP address, `nginx` will use the name to match the vhost that should handle the request to the one in the `Host` header of the http request. In your case with two vhosts but different protocols (http/https), the protocol (or rather the `Listen` port) will be used to differentiate further between the two vhosts.

Comment: I get conflicting server error in `systemctl status nginx` if I name them the same. However, I can still access my site. Is it fine to ignore the error?

Comment: Then maybe you should post the exact config excerpts and error messages. Edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The server names are an important part of your nginx configuration. If you server multiple domains/sub-domains from a server with a single public IP, the `server_name` directive tells nginx what server should respond to a request. If there is no matching server name, nginx will next look for a default server that, if present, act as some sort of 'catch all' server.

Here's a **configuration example** for http -> https redirect where you can also see how to name servers correctly without getting errors.

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/www.example.com.vhost**

```
# This server will redirect all http -> https
server {
        # Listen for both IPv4 and IPv6 requests.
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name www.example.com example.com;

        # This section assuming you're using Let's Encrypt / certbot
        location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
            default_type "text/plain";
            root         /path/to/your/document/root
        }
        location = /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
            return 404;
        }

        # Here's where your 301 permanent redirect to the https:/www version happens.
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;

}

# This server will redirect all https requests without www to the version with www
server {
        # Listen for both IPv4 and IPv6 requests and activate http2.
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name example.com;

        ssl on;
        # Paths to certificates assuming you're using Let's Encrypt / certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem;
        # There's much more directives you should fine tune for https, but that's another task.

        # Here's where your 301 permanent redirect to the https://www version happens.
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

# This server will actually server your https content.
server {
        # Listen for both IPv4 and IPv6 requests and activate http2.
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name www.example.com;

        ssl on;
        # Paths to certificates assuming you're using let's encrypt / certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem;
        # There's much more directives you should fine tune for https, but that's another task.

        ####
        #
        # Your server directives go here.
        #
        ####
}
```